# Twilio CLI fails to install serverless plugin

Tags: twilio

I'm running the Twilio CLI and trying to install the serverless plugin. I run the command `twilio plugins:install @twilio-labs/plugin-serverless` and it'll start to work but then it gets to `Installing plugin @twilio-labs/plugin-serverless... / [2/4] Fetching packages...`, stops running, and jumps to a new line. Any idea why this isn't installing?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was using an old version of Node (10.13.0), I updated to the latest v10 version 10.20.1 and it seemed to fix the issue.

Could have been that some of the new dependencies require a newer version of node and so the install is unable to complete. Probably should show an error.

--verbose didn't really show anything helpful.